# shell curl and shell zip error

Tags: php, wamp

I want to install a php code on my hosting, it shows me `Shell unzip and Shell cURL command not present` error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code probably contain some cURL function which call cURL library that you've obviously not installed.

Here's the documentation for cURL if you want install it :
http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: my code requirement is  GD Library and ImageMagick. so for GD Library curl is enable...